# Multiple hops tunnels howto

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I wonder if anyone is able to help me with multiple tunnel hops for servers...

basically my setup looks something like this...

```
[desktop01]=====[server01]=====[server02]---------[machine01]
                                         \--------[machine02]
                                          \-------[machine03]
                                           \------[machine04]
```

I want to setup some ssh tunnels so that from my desktop I can ssh directly to machine01 through 04 without having to ssh to each box in between in turn...

So desktop01 can only see server01, server02 can only accept connections from server01 and machines 01 to 04 only accept connections from server02.

Can anyone help as im really stuck with this.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration in `~/.ssh/config` allows you to dynamically setup jump hosts by separating them with the `%` symbol:

```
Host *%*
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f2-) nc $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f1) %p
```

You could then run `ssh machine01%server02%server01` and it would connect to machine01 via server01 and server02. (This doesn't work so well when you need to specify non-default usernames unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could construct something like the following with port fowardings:

(Syntax:  `lport:remotehost:rport`, which means "Forward port lport on the local machine to rport on the remote machine)

```
 [server01]            [server02]
 22001:server02:22001  22001:machine01:22  
 22002:server02:22002  22002:machine02:22  
 22003:server02:22003  22003:machine03:22  
 22004:server02:22004  22004:machine04:22
```

You can then just do an `ssh -p 22001 usernamefrom_machine01@server01` to connect to `machine01` with the relevant username.

To construct the port forwardings, use either the `-L` option of ssh or configure it with the help of your `~/.ssh/config` file.

For details, see `man ssh` and `man ssh_config`.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered with several options over at superuser.com  https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops